# How to use list of images as input of CNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, image, list, tensorflow

I'm a newbie of TensorFlow, I have a problem when using list as inputs for CNN.

Let say that I have 4 list:

- `TrainingImage`: This is a list that has all images that I want to train, each image I is BGR channels,, so i put image I to this list by using `TrainingImage.append(I)`.
- `TrainingLabel`: This is a list for labeling image in `TrainingImage`, each row is a one-hot vector. For example if I have 3 object (1, 2, 3), each object has 2 images (which mean `TrainingImage` has 3 x 2 = 6 images), then I have a list of label like: 1, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1
- `TestingImage`: List that has all images for test, similar to `TrainingImage` but fewer images.
- `TestingLabel`: List that has all label of `TestingImage`

I don't know how to use it as inputd for CNN in TensorFlow. I'm using the following code, each image has size 68 x 68 x 3, I have 17 object, each object I have 64 images for training, 16 images for testing.

> with tf.Session() as sess:
>
> ```
> data_initializer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
>                                   (1088, 68, 68, 3))
> label_initializer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
>                                    (1088, 17))
> input_data = tf.Variable(data_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[])
> input_labels = tf.Variable(label_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[])
>
> sess.run(input_data.initializer, feed_dict={data_initializer: TrainingImage})
> sess.run(input_labels.initializer, feed_dict={label_initializer: TrainingLabel})
> ```

So now `input_data` and `input_labels` is my new input for CNN but I'm not sure this is a right way? I'm using those above code by following this TensorFlow instruction https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#preloaded_data, treat 4 lists as variables.

Comment: can you try converting list of images to numpy array ? a = [1, 2] ; a = np.asarray(a)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that'll work.  May I recommend that instead of

```
data_initializer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(1088, 68, 68, 3))
```

you use

```
data_initializer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None, 68, 68, 3))
```

This will allow you to send in different amounts of images instead of always having to send in 1088 images.  At some point you way want to process just 1 image.

Comment: Thanks, but when I change to None, this error happen ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Placeholder_4:0", shape=(?, 68, 68, 3), dtype=float32)

Comment: try changing *"input_data = tf.Variable(data_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[])"* to **input_data = tf.Variable(tf.zeros( [ None,68,68,3 ] , dtype=tf.float32 ), trainable=False, collections=[])** , and similarly input_labels